# Regex pattern to match a string like : +500-+600

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex pattern to match strings like:

```
+500-+600
```

The pattern should only accept `+` when there is a number after, and should only accept `-` (hyphen) between two numbers.

So far I could only get the pattern working for the `+` which is:

```
/^\+?([0-9]+)$/
```

But I couldn't figure out how to add the `-` to the pattern.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: Not entirely clear but maybe you're looking for something like `/^\+?[0-9]+(?:-\+?[0-9]+)*$/`? Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MeFMLu/1). Note that a literal "+" needs to be escaped (i.e., `\+`). Also, you didn't mention that the "+" is optional but based on your pattern, it looks like that's what you want. If not, just remove the `?` after `+`.

Comment: @M.Maria you're being very confusing here. Can you properly format your questions, with examples it should match and the examples it should not, to provide some clarity? sample input/output would help everyone involved

Comment: Thank you so much 41686d6564, this works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a special character in regex, so you must escape it with `\` if you want to interpret it as a string literal.

```
/^\+\d+-\+\d+$/
```

This will match all strings where you have two numbers separated by a hyphen (as per your example `+500-+600`).

---

If the second number is optional but there can only be two numbers, use this:

```
/^\+\d+(-\+\d+)?$/
```

This matches:

```
+500
+500-+600
```

---

If there can be any number of additional hyphen-separated numbers, use this:

```
/^\+\d+(-\+\d+)*$/
```

This matches:

```
+500
+500-+600
+500-+600-+700
```